# Referencing a DLL that uses an older version of EF

Tags: .net, entity-framework, dll

In my WCF service project, I am using EF 6.1.1, in the same project I added a reference to a library that uses EF 4.3. Whenever I call any method in the library that needs EF it throws an error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=4.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

How can I solve that without changing the EF version in the library to match the service version (or vice versa)?

Answer (score 0):

If there were no breaking changes in the API you might be able to use assembly binding redirection.  If you add the following to your .config file the 6.1.1 EF assembly should be loaded instead of a bound earlier version:

```
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.3.1.0-6.1.1.0" newVersion="6.1.1.0"/>
         </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
```